# C++ Multiple initialization error with generating random numbers

Tags: c++

When I run my code:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;

int x;
int y;
int z;

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(1, 10000000);
    int a = dis(gen);
    printf("%d", a);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(1, 10000000);
    int b = dis(gen);
    printf("%d", b);
```

It generates 'error C2374: 'gen' : redefinition; multiple initialization' errors. How do I fix this? Do I have to use only part of the code to generate 2 different numbers? Also, if I want to change 1-10000000 to 1-20 for a third variable, how would I do that?

Comment: Don't repeat the first 3 lines. You already have the generator, you just want the next number from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
...
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
```

Don't do the initialization of `gen` twice. Just do it once. Use different variables - with different names, for different things.

Also, don't define the global variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `y` and `z`. They are totally useless. Define every variable as locally as you can.